# .to_json on Array() not working in Crystal

Tags: arrays, json, crystal-lang

I have a class:

```
class User
    property id : Int32?
    property email : String?
    property password : String?

    def to_json : String
        JSON.build do |json|
            json.object do
                json.field "id", self.id
                json.field "email", self.email
                json.field "password", self.password
            end
        end
    end

    # other stuff
end
```

This works great with any `user.to_json`. But when I have `Array(User)` (`users.to_json`) it throws this error at compile time:

> in /usr/local/Cellar/crystal-lang/0.23.1_3/src/json/to_json.cr:66: no
>   overload matches 'User#to_json' with type JSON::Builder Overloads are:
>    - User#to_json()
>    - Object#to_json(io : IO)
>    - Object#to_json()
>
> ```
>   each &.to_json(json)
> ```

`Array(String)#to_json` works fine, so why doesn't `Array(User)#to_json`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array(User)#to_json` doesn't work because `User` needs to have `to_json(json : JSON::Builder)` method (not `to_json`), just like [String has](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/b52b2f93dd037a12f33354b05fe26a61e1b33662/src/json/to_json.cr#L51-L55):

```
require "json"

class User
  property id : Int32?
  property email : String?
  property password : String?

  def to_json(json : JSON::Builder)
    json.object do
      json.field "id", self.id
      json.field "email", self.email
      json.field "password", self.password
    end
  end
end

u = User.new.tap do |u|
  u.id = 1
  u.email = "test@email.com"
  u.password = "****"
end

u.to_json      #=> {"id":1,"email":"test@email.com","password":"****"}
[u, u].to_json #=> [{"id":1,"email":"test@email.com","password":"****"},{"id":1,"email":"test@email.com","password":"****"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed other problems too.

Comment: Also have a look at `JSON.mapping`, which might cleanup your code a bit.